# How to advertise HTTPS RR locally?

Tags: domain-name-system, https, internal-dns, quic, http3

Trying to host a HTTP3-only server locally on port 443 and have a local web browser access it.

Tested the HTTP3 server directly with a cli client and that is working

Attempting to use a `HTTPS` DNS resource record (RR) defined by [IETF RFC 9460](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9460) to make the browser jump straight to using QUIC rather than attempt a TCP connection. Installed [Knot DNS](https://www.knot-dns.cz) 3.3.2 and added the following entries:

```
$ORIGIN local-server-domain.
@ 60 IN HTTPS 1 . alpn=h3
@ 60 IN A 127.0.0.1
@ 60 IN AAAA ::1
```

such that when I inspect Knot DNS I get this output:

```
$ knotc zone-read --
[local-server-domain.] local-server-domain. 60 A 127.0.0.1
[local-server-domain.] local-server-domain. 3600 SOA ns.local-server-domain. hostmaster.local-server-domain. 1 43200 900 1209600 3600
[local-server-domain.] local-server-domain. 60 AAAA ::1
[local-server-domain.] local-server-domain. 60 HTTPS 1 . alpn=h3
```

and when I point `/etc/resolv.conf` to use `nameserver 127.0.0.1` I'm able to correctly resolve the `local-server-domain`:

```
$ nslookup local-server-domain
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   local-server-domain
Address: 127.0.0.1
Name:   local-server-domain
Address: ::1
```

However, when I try to access `https://local-server-domain` with IceCat v115, [which should support HTTP RR since v92](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/92#http), It doesn't get the HTTPS RR and thus continues to try TCP which predictably fails:

[image: Wireshark output]

I also tried variations based on examples I've seen but with the same results:

```
$ORIGIN local-server-domain.
@ 60 IN HTTPS 1 . alpn=h3
```

```
$ORIGIN local-server-domain.
@ 60 IN HTTPS 1 . alpn=h3
@ 60 IN A 127.0.0.1
```

```
$ORIGIN local-server-domain.
@ 60 IN HTTPS 1 . alpn=h3
@ 60 IN A 127.0.0.1
@ 60 IN NS ns
ns 60 IN A 127.0.0.1
```

### Question

How do I setup the `HTTPS` RR such that it gets provided to my browser?

Not sure if this matters but my build of Knot DNS does not support DNS-over-QUIC (DoQ) but my understanding is that I'm just trying to get an unencrypted DNS record so this is not needed.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details on the browser side, but "It doesn't get the HTTPS RR" really looks to be "It didn't even attempt to look up the HTTPS RR" based on the packet dump. Which at least leads me to believe this is about browser-side behavior... maybe this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1813704

Comment: Oh wow you're right @HåkanLindqvist. Although the bug is for the Android version of Firefox (Fenix) it does happen on the desktop version as well. Just tested the steps as described and compared it to what Chrome does and I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: I took a step back and created another question to ask about the mechanics of this DNS RR: https://serverfault.com/questions/1151933/how-does-a-web-browser-use-a-https-or-svcb-dns-resource-record-rr and how to validate that it's working for a client in the wild.