# How does a web browser use a HTTPS or SVCB DNS Resource Record (RR)?

Tags: domain-name-system, https, http3, browser

#### Background

[IETF RFC 9460](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9460) defines `SVCB` and `HTTPS` DNS resource record (RR) which can be used to upgrade connections to HTTPS and also specify the application-layer protocols that are supported (ALPN).

On September 7, 2021 Firefox 92 was released which [added support for the HTTPS RR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/92#http):

> Firefox will automatically upgrade an HTTP request to HTTPS when a usable HTTPS RR is available. It will also use information provided in an HTTPS RR to optimize the process of establishing HTTPS connections⁠—this is conceptually similar to using the Alt-Svc header. ([Firefox bug 1721132](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1721132)).

#### Test

Trying to test this out with `www.google.com`.

First, I tried to see if it had an `HTTPS` RR:

```
$ dig 8.8.8.8 www.google.com HTTPS

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     3358    IN  HTTPS   1 . alpn="h2,h3"
```

Here we see that the `HTTPS` RR does exist and we notice that HTTP/3 is a supported protocol denoted by the `h3` value of the `alpn` parameter.

Next, tried to clear my operating system's DNS cache. For example, on windows, I ran `ipconfig /flushdns`.
Also ran this right before pressing enter on the address bar because Firefox and Chrome (or some other process) seems to try to reach google.com a lot on one of the systems I was testing with.

Opened up Firefox v120 and attempted to visit: `www.google.com`.

#### Problem

Firefox v120, although stated in the v92 release that it will use a HTTPS RR to upgrade and optimise, doesn't seem to ask for it.

Wireshark shows that only `A` and `AAAA` RR are queried:

[image: wireshark]

And Firefox can be seen initially opening an HTTP/2 connection before switching to HTTP/3 because of the `Alt-Svc` header:

[image: firefox]

Actually, it doesn't appear like any (Chrome, IceCat, Edge, etc.) desktop application, on multiple websites, ask for the `HTTPS` RR at all because when I filter for `dns.qry.type == "HTTPS"` or `dns.qry.type == 65` on WireShark I don't get any hits. I only get hits when I explicitly do a lookup via `dig`.

#### Question

Why does it appear that the `HTTPS` RR is never queried?

To try to understand the issue, I'm also asking these leading questions which might help find the root cause:

- Is this a feature that is disabled by default?
- Does this depend on the host setup (other than setting up the `HTTPS` RR)? No resource I've read indicated that additional steps are needed.
- Whose responsibility is it to ask for the `HTTPS` RR? Is it the browser or operating system? So far I've tried it with updated versions of Guix System 1.4, Windows 10, and Windows 11 and all the browsers I mentioned above.
- Does this depend on hardware?

Comment: Thought this was an interesting comment from GitHub. Implementation seems spotty and vapor-y.  https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/6091#issuecomment-1819649621 https://www.netmeister.org/blog/https-rrs.html "Safari seems to support it fully; Firefox supports it fully iff using DoH; Chrome currently only supports the 'ech' field."

Comment: The DoH part is interesting. They probably thought an HTTPS record would be creating another target for attackers. MITM.